# Nodejs - Variable is not accessible inside promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, strongloop

I want to add object to the local variable inside promise but the variable is not accessible inside that, here's the code, please focus on the comments "accessible here and not accessible here":

```
        var dfs = [];

        var createDFs = function(item, index) {

          var country = item._id;
          item.country = (countries[0][country.toUpperCase()]);

          var findComps = Complete.find({'country': country});

          findComps.then(function(comps) {
            item.complete = comps;
            //dfs.push(item); //doesn't work here
          });

          dfs.push(item); //works here but item.comps not accessible

        };



        data.forEach(createDFs);
```

Comment: Probably `dfs.push(item);` is working but you are not seeing the items because the callbacks has not been executed yet. Why do you say that is not working?

Comment: try     
          findComps.then((comps)=> {
            item.complete = comps;
            //dfs.push(item); //doesn't work here
          });

Comment: @Mikethetechy, tried it and it doesn't work.